# need help on using arguments out the function decorator in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to use parameters outside of the decarator, i tried using it but getting below error

I am using flask API endpoints to give arg parameters such as source, destination and prot and protcol and SDC , DDC

In my casse when i use /t2e/ get method i have to use four parameters but when i use /junos/ then need to use 6 parametes , i dont want to repeat 4 parameters such as source, destination and prot and protcol. hence i tried use them above the method  as below

Non working and getting error as

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from  main.hunter_function import t2e, junos,

method = Flask(__name__)


args = request.args
source = args.get('source')
destination = args.get('destination')
port = args.get('port')
protocol = args.get('protocol')

@method.route('/t2e/', methods=['GET']) # is a decorator used to match URLs to view functions in Flask apps
def method_t2e():

    logger.info("method is fetching t2e output")
    output = t2e(source, destination, port, protocol)
    return output
@method.route('/junos/', methods=['GET']) # is a decorator used to match URLs to view functions in Flask apps
def method_junos():
    sdc = args.get('sdc') 
    ddc = args.get("ddc")       
    logger.info("method is fetching Junos output from link")
    output = jun(source, destination, port, protocol,sdc,ddc)
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    method.run(ssl_context="adhoc",host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)
```

Here is working code:

```
@method.route('/t2e/', methods=['GET']) # is a decorator used to match URLs to view functions in Flask apps
def method_t2e():
    args = request.args
    source = args.get('source')
    destination = args.get('destination')
    port = args.get('port')
    protocol = args.get('protocol')
    logger.info("method is fetching t2e output")
    output = t2e(source, destination, port, protocol)
    return output
@method.route('/junos/', methods=['GET']) # is a decorator used to match URLs to view functions in Flask apps
def method_junos():
    args = request.args
    source = args.get('source')
    sdc = args.get('sdc')
    destination = args.get('destination')
    ddc = args.get("ddc")
    port = args.get('port')
    protocol = args.get('protocol')
    logger.info("method is fetching Junos output from link")
    output = jun(source, destination, port, protocol,sdc,ddc)
    return output
```

I don't want to repeat the parameters more than once

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which returns those to reduce code duplication such as

```py
def get_args(args):
    return args.get('source'), args.get('destination'), args.get('port'), args.get('protocol')

@method.route('/t2e/', methods=['GET']) 
def method_t2e():
    args = request.args
    source, destination, port, protocol = get_args(args)
```

The issue with what you're trying to do is the request variable doesn't exist outside the call to your methods so in order to get them you need to pass the specific request for the method somewhere